# angularJS problems on tomcat - application restarts on page/controller-change

Tags: node.js, tomcat, angularjs

For my local angularJS development, I'm using nodeJS. If I deploy my angularJS project on a tomcat server, it basically works BUT, I'm using different pages and different controllers and every time I click on the other page, it seems that the whole application is restarted again, because the data in the rootscope is lost and it starts program parts which should be started on application startup only.

Can anybody tell me whats going wrong here?
Why is my application not 100 % correct running on tomcat?

I'm using tomcat 7.0.34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Tomcat, but we've had the same issue with Apache. As Angular needs to do the routing of your app itself, you have to tell your web server to always deliver your root HTML page, e.g. `index.html`.

After doing that, your app should work fine.

Comment: i used <a href="index.html#/home">home</a> instead of <a href="#/home">home</a> ... now it works... thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you say `different page` you literally mean a different html page (url).That is the expected behaviour. AngularJS is a Single Page Application (SPA) framework. Like any other SPA it gets reinitialized when you do a full page load\reload or you navigate to another page.

This is due to stateless nature of HTTP. Every page is an independent request, which starts the client side page life cycle.

For using AngularJS correctly as  SPA, you need to have a main page. The content of this pages gets alter\appended by child views\partials (again pages). AngularJS also hijacks the browser url chnanges so that this does not cause full page reloads on url change.

Look at some sample applications created using AngularJS to understand how it works.